# How to give time delay in alert msg ok button event in sencha touch

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

```
I am new to sencha touch mobile and my issue is when i am clicking the alert MSG OK button my list view is also getting the click event in the portion of OK button . So i need to put some time delay before hiding the alert and clicking OK, can any one help how to give some time delay in alert OK button event or any other solution for the fix. Please find the below code. Thanks in advance.
```

Ext.Msg.alert('', 'Data saved successfully', function(btn, text){

```
if (btn == 'ok'){

// DO WORK

//Ext.defer(function(){ console.log('ok clicked');},400);

}else{
return false;
}
});
```

Answer (score 4):

if you want to add a delay, you could use the built in setTimeout method:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  // do your work here
}, 400);
```